# How to make Form1 call a method by command of Form2

Tags: c#, winforms, nullpointerexception

I'm getting stuck here every time and obviously I can never find a way to run things by the rule book. :(
I have a method in Form1 and I want to call it from Form2. Or: Command Form1 by Form2.
I called it from Form2 but then I get a NullPointerExp:

Form2:

```
    private Form1 f1;

    public Form2(Form1 of)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f1 = of;
    }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.callMethod(3,3,1);
        Form.ActiveForm.Close();
    }
```

This method creates a button array in a panel placed in Form1 (guess there is the problem).

I tried to pass the arguments for callMethod() to Form1 to class variables. Somehow I'm sure this is bad style anyway. Still the method had to be called after all.

I got an idea to create some kind of listener in Form1: 
Disable Form1 until OK is pressed in Form2, then callMethod + passed arguments passed by Form2, or cancel.

Just don't know which is the best way. Should I pass arguments and listen in Form1? Or really try to get callMethod working in Form1, if called in Form2?
Somebody got an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your code showing how you initialize form2? Looks like you are most likely passing a null reference at that point.  That or form1 is closed and no longer exists. Your initializer should look something like this (inside form1) `var frm2 = new Form2(this); frm2.Show();`

Comment: Also, fairly positive this is a duplicate but I'm using my phone and having trouble locating it

Comment: This is how I call Form2:

Form2 userF = new Form2();
userF.Show();

Comment: Well that's why. You need to pass the current instance of form1 to the constructor as in my first comment. Otherwise it is null and that's where your null exception comes from. You should be getting compile errors because your constructor for form2 requires an argument, unless you have a default one that takes no arguments that you have not shown here.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that. Fairly easy I guess. Thank you very much! =) Learned never stops.

Comment: I will post as an answer. Please accept. Give me a second

Comment: When you have multiple Button controls ... use the CommandName property to specify or determine the command name associated with each Button control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Nothing here suggests a web page. It is tagged C# and WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the current instance of form1 to the constructor as in my first comment. Otherwise it is null and that's where your null exception comes from. You should be getting compile errors because your constructor for form2 requires an argument, unless you have a default one that takes no arguments that you have not shown here.

Change your method inside of Form1 to do this:

```
Form2 userF = new Form2(this); // pass this to the constructor
userF.Show();
```

The **this** refers to the current instance of your object, in this case the current instance of the Form1 object that is calling Form2. This will call your constructor of Form2 that takes the argument and your null reference exception will go away. The **this** keyword is equivalent to the **Me** keyword in VB.NET, if you are familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the method static and call it by calling:

```
Form1.DoSomething();
```

By your needs, it's:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private static void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.DoSomething(parameters);
    Form.ActiveForm.Close();
}
```

The function in Form1 would be something like this:

```
public static void xxx(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

The difference is the **static** attribute.

Comment: This is assuming it's ok to be static. From the question he needs to control a specific form1 so static is out of the question

Comment: From what I understood, he wants to simply call the method, you're the one who went wrong there.

Comment: _This method creates a button array in a panel placed in Form1_ if the method is static on which form you would create the button array?

Comment: I disagree. He refers to controlling form1,even considers adding listeners which would only work on a specific one. Either way the question is too vague at exactly what he's attempting to do, but it definitely appears that a static method would not be what he needs as he is working with specific instances.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it's not possible to make the method static.